# Better way to Display forms one on top of another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Main form.I want to launch another form from it and launch another from the launched form.I want to ensure that the Main form is not editable when sub forms are displayed so i use `showdialog()`

**Mainform>(Showdialog)>form1>(showDialog+dispose)>form2(dispose)>Mainform**

From Mainform i call form2.ShowDialog() then from form2 i use the following code to launch another form

```
this.visible=false;
form3.showdialog();
this.dispose();
```

But there are some problems in this.Is there a better way to achieve what im looking for?

```
edit:more description
```

I have a Main form,User clicks a Button on Mainform>Form1 is lauched>User clicks a Button in Form1>Form 2 is lauched(diposing/hiding form1) after form2 is closed Mainform should be brought to front and made editable,until then all other forms should be on top of Mainform and Mainform should be un-editable

Comment: What are the specific problems you have encountered?

Comment: From what you've described (producing child forms such that the parent form cannot be edited by the user), ShowDialog() does exactly what you're looking for, and is the simplest and best way of achieving what you're looking for. You'll have to be more specific about the problems you're running into for any further help. I suspect those problems are not specific to the ShowDialog() call.

Comment: @Josh The Main form is editable when Form2 is shown and in some cases the Form2 goes Behind Mainform and i have to bring it to the top manually from the taskbar icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have to specify the MainForm as the parent for (both) form2 and form3. When you use the overload of ShowDialog that has no parameters, WinForms uses the active form as the parent, so form3's parent becomes form2 automatically. You are then trying to close/dispose form2 causing form3 to become orphaned.

There are several options for getting the reference to MainForm, but the simplest is to use:

```
form2/3.ShowDialog(Application.OpenForms["MainForm"]);
```

Assuming that you have set the Name property on MainForm to "MainForm".

Comment: So when i close Form3 after opening from Form2 will the control go back to Mainform.Should i use Dispose() or close().Please give an Example

Comment: @techno The question is nonsensical. A modal dialog (Form) is closed by itself as the user cannot interact with anything else. You close it from within itself by setting the DialogResult property. This is usually accomplished by setting the DialogResult property of the various buttons, usually an Ok button set to DialogResult.Ok and a Cancel button set to DialogResult.Cancel. I think we need more information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have a Main form,User clicks a Button on Mainform>Form1 is lauched>User clicks a Button in Form1>Form 2 is lauched(diposing/hiding form1) after form2 is closed Mainform should be editable,until then all other forms should be on top of Mainform and Mainform should be un-editable

Comment: i believe @Tergiver gave you the answer to your problem already, show all forms with yourForm.ShowDialog(Application.OpenForms["MainForm"]) parameter, and your problems go away!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, this.dispose() is executed only after form3 is closed. What i think you want is to close form2 after form3 was closed, so you can call this.Close() instead of this.Dispose().

```
this.visible=false;
form3.showdialog();
this.Close();
```

Or maybe, after form3 is shown up you dont need form2 any more. That meas:

```
this.visible=false;
//show instead of showdialog so it wont wait until form3 is closed
form3.show();
this.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to implement something like a wizard. The best solution would be to launch all the child forms sequentially, in the main form.

If you need to pass data along the sequence, you should pass it from each dialog to the main form, which then passes it to the next dialog.

Comment: If it's true that @techno is trying to create a wizard, the best way is to use UserControls as the "pages", and swap them in and out of the form as the user progresses.

Answer (score 0):

MainForm:

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
if (f.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Form1 (button click which will open the form 2):

```
button1_click(object sender, EvengArgs e) {
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    Close();   
}
```